# SFTP upload vs save issue

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

is there any option to set case sensitive file saving?

My issue is when I press Ctrl+S, it saves and uploads to server but lower-case only, but when I upload it by right click -> Upload, it uploads correctly.

Image about file explorer

[image: 1]

Any Idea?

Comment: When you are working on Windows it might help to set [case sensitivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/case-sensitivity)  (Quote: "The Windows file system supports setting case sensitivity with attribute flags per directory. While the standard behavior is to be case-insensitive, you can assign an attribute flag to make a directory case sensitive, so that it will recognize Linux files and folders that may differ only by case." )

Comment: Sorry, just did set this flag, Windows does see the difference, but Visual Studio Code does not see the difference.  So, with Visual Studio Code there is no option.

Comment: see also: [vscode issue 'not a bug'/'by design'](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/121106), and [Document expectations around filename casing](https://github.com/microsoft/language-server-protocol/issues/1263)